# How to use less UIviewController in an app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimage

Good day all, I am new to xcode and my motivation is developing an app with electrical circuits. I have started building it but there are just too many `UIViewControllers` as I have to repeat the diagram on another one even if they have similar components e.g. buttons, inputs and outputs.

Any idea on how to minimize `UIVIewControllers`? Like maybe I can store those input and output (as buttons) then call them based on different scenarios one `UIViewController`? (considering similar input/output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a subclass of UIViewController that automatically creates all of the common components, then just add to / configure each instance.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks. Does his mean I cn just do a code for all the components I have with the same "board" then can just call which components I need for a certain circuit?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of options, You can add as many UIViews as a subView as you want. But I m also an Electrical Engineer by qualification ,so it is not a good idea. You have to make those subviews again and again. You can do following approach.

1. Make a `ViewController` of a reusable  Component Like Power Source, Resistance etc. You can set custom size of that `ViewController` By selecting the `ViewController` and setting the size to free form in size in Attribute inspector.
2. You can add labels on those `ViewController` (components) and set the dynamic value of those components as well.
3. You can set the Background Color of those `ViewController` as a clear color so that it will not hide any wire or component beneath it.

Comment: Thanks Asifhabib, will wok on search more on how to do this.